# How to not overwrite the json contents and also append new items - python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am coding in python and I'm using json to save the data however I always got an error in json file. I am using a nested dict. It's appending but creating a new nested dict, not into the original nested dict

My target output is

```
{
    "1234" : {
                  Name: "wkwkw"
                  Age: "15"
             }
    "54321" : {
                  Name: "wkwkw"
                  Age: "15"
             }

}
```

but I keep getting

```
{
    "1234" : {
                  Name: "wkwkw"
                  Age: "15"
             }
}
{    
   "54321" : {
                  Name: "wkwkw"
                  Age: "15"
             }

}
```

which always error

this is my code

```
    def register(self):
        self.emp_id = input("Employee ID: ")
        self.password = input("Password: ")

        employee_record = {}
        employee_details = {self.emp_id : employee_record}
        employee_record["Employee ID"] = self.emp_id
        employee_record["Password"] = self.password
        employee_record["Job"] = self.job
        employee_record["Name"] = self.name
        employee_record["Age"] = self.age
        employee_record["Gender"] = self.gender
        employee_record["Contact Number"] = self.contact_no

        print("Registration Successful!")
        #print(employee_record)

        with open('emp_details.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(employee_details, fp, indent=4)
        fp.close()
    
    def login(self):
        file = open("emp_details.json", 'r')
        emp_login_details = json.load(file)

        print (emp_login_details)

        self.emp_id = input("Enter login ID: ")
        self.password = input("Enter your password: ")

        if self.emp_id in emp_login_details[self.emp_id]["Employee ID"]:
            if self.password in emp_login_details[self.emp_id]["Password"]:
                print("You are now logged in!")
        else:
            print("You are not logged in!")

        file.close()
```

Comment: If you want to append to JSON you either have the generator creating the whole file new, or - and this is kinde tricky and should only done for biiiig JSON - you manually fiddle with the JSON syntax and inject it to the right position. 
But as you are using `w` as file opening option, I am wondering if not all content is deleted and replaced by only the latest entry ...

Comment: As a general concern: What are you trying to do here? Printing the employe data of all employees directly prior login is for debugging, right? Right? Storing passwords in cleartext in a JSON is hopefully also only for testing / learning,

Comment: this is just apply json in a simple program. I just want to know to the latest entry will append and not just overwrite the old employee record